# unable to sqoop data from oracle data source using split by on date column

Tags: hive, sqoop

**query:**

```
sqoop import --connect "*****" \
--username ****
-P ******
--query "select * from table_name where trunc(date_column)>=ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate,'YEAR'),-12) and \$CONDITIONS" \
--split-by date_column \
-m 4
```

**error:**

[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p09K3.jpg)

the error is caused by java.sql.SQL.DataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match string format. Please find the attached image for more description of error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the format of the split-by column. Try formatting the split-by column as: --split-by "to_number(to_char(date_column, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS'))" 
or to whatever format is required.